# My query about my CTC, Gross salary and net pay

Tags: india, income, salary, adjusted-gross-income

I am working as Software professional in reputed private concern.

After one year of my successful completion, they offered me 3 lakhs per annum package. But I am getting only Rs 20606 as net pay per month. As per the Govt regulation it should be 22495. Please let me know If they are paying correctly or wrongly...

Please find my pay slip below....

Thanks in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

> As per the Govt regulation it should be 22495

Not sure which regulation you are taking about.

> they offered me 3 lakhs per annum package

Unless you show the offer letter giving the break-up, it is hard to tell. There are quite a few companies who add various other items as CTC, for example premium paid towards group insurance, Gratuity, etc.

> But I am getting only Rs 20606 as net pay per month.

The payslip shows your Gross as 22589 with deductions towards PF and Profession tax as 1983. Thus you net take home is 20606

Comment: My question is - I have hike letter from my company for 3 Lakhs. But my CTC is 25000. As per the calculation, Gross Salary = Cost to Company (CTC) - Employer's PF Contribution (EPF) - Gratuity. i.e Gross Salary = 25,000.00 - 900.00 – 400.00 = 23,700.00

Take Home Salary = Gross Salary - Income Tax - Employee's PF Contribution (PF) - Prof. Tax.
Take Home Salary = 23,700.00 - 0.00 – 900.00 – 200.00 = 22,600.00.
But my net pay is 20606. That's my doubt.Please help me to find the gap.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the break-up of 3 lakhs in the letter?

Answer (score 0):

There will be a few components that are mentioned in the offer letter but not shown on the payslip. Example is gratuity.

Then, there will a few components not mentioned in the offer letter but will appear on payslip. Example: deduction towards a corpus which helps employees in need.

Some companies show canteen expenses as a part of CTC as a single annual figure - say 18000 Rs. But monthly deductions may not be uniform (18000/12 = 1500). Thus, you cannot infer midway whether your monthly pay is following CTC. Things become even more complex if you have variable pay which is paid out on a quarterly basis.